# Find Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a simple graph with order $n$, the minimum degree $\delta\geq \frac{n+q}{2}$, prove that for any pairwise non-adjacent $q$ edges, there exists a Hamiltonian cycle $H$ contains these edges.

---

I want to choose a Hamiltonian cycle $H'$ contains these edges as much as possible, then define $S$ and $T$ such that
$$n+q\leq d(u)+d(v)=|S|+|T|=|S \cup T|+|S\cap T|\leq n+q-1$$
to induce contradiction, but I don't know how to define $S$ and $T$, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract all $q$ edges to get $G’$. $G’$ has order $n-q$ and minimum degree $\delta ‘ \geq \frac{n-q}{2}$ since it cannot decrease more than the order did. Since the minimum degree is at lest half the order, $G’$ is Hamiltonian as proven by Dirac.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is amazing!